# Web page text on mobile increasing in size when it receives a message from our mqtt broker

Tags: javascript, html, mqtt

When I get a message from our mqtt broker, the text on my mobile web page increases and I have no idea why it is doing it. Please help. Look for yourself. Sorry for how messy it is; I am new to coding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    .myClass {
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: left;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: auto;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
 </template>
  <title>Sprinkler System</title>
  <p id="System" class="myClass"></p>
  <p id="PumpPres" class="myClass"></p>
  <p id="PumpCurrent" class="myClass"></p>
  <h6><i>This is in develoupement build</i></h6>

  <h3>Message<br>
    <input type="text" id="InputRandom"></input> <input onclick="Random1()" type="button" value="Send Message" id="Input2"></input>
  </h3>
  <br>
  <h4> Sprinkler System <br><input type="number" id="InputTxt" min="1" max="12"></input>
    <input onclick="SS_On()" type="button" value="Turn On"></input>
    <input onclick="SS_Off()" type="button" value="Turn Off" id="RandomBtn"></input>
  </h4>
  <p id="this" class="myClass"></p>
  <input onclick="reset()" type="button" value="reset"></input>
  <p id="mic"></p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
    /*=============================================Variables================================================*/
    var HomeLog = "home/irrigation/state";
    var LogSS = "home/irrigation/log";
    var SS_dest = "home/irrigation"; //SS == Sprinkler System
    var SS_Pres = "home/irrigation/pressure";
    var SS_Current = "home/irrigation/pump_current"
    var Ip = "192.168.1.46"; //ip adress of the broker
    var Port = Number(8083); //port of the broker
    var Id = makeid(); //writes the ip
    var mes; //makes mes global
    var num = 0;
    var Log;
    /*==============================================MQTT====================================*/
    client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(Ip, Port, Id);

    // set callback handlers
    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

    // connect the client
    client.connect({
      onSuccess: onConnect
    });

    // called when the client connects
    function onConnect() {

      // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
      console.log("Connected as " + makeid());
      client.subscribe(SS_dest);
      client.subscribe(LogSS);
      client.subscribe(HomeLog);
      client.subscribe(SS_Pres);
      client.subscribe(SS_Current);
    }

    // called when the client loses its connection
    function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
      var TimeOut;
      var Object1 = responseObject.errorCode;
      if (Object1 !== 0) {
        console.log("ConnectionLost:" + responseObject.errorMessage);
        //client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(Ip, Port, Id);
        client.connect({
          onSuccess: onConnect
        });
        TimeOut++;
      }
      if (TimeOut == 10) {
        Object1 = 1;
      }
    }

    // called when a message arrives
    function onMessageArrived(message) {
      var OnOff;
      console.log("MessageArrived:" + message.payloadString);
      mes = message.payloadString;
      //alert(mes);


      var res = mes.split(","); //holds if statement
      if (res[1] == "on" || res[1] == "On") {
        OnOff = "On";

      } else if (res[1] == "Off" || res[1] == "Off") {
        OnOff = "Off";
      }
      var Test1 = res.length;
      if (Test1 >= 2) {
        //alert(Test1);
        document.getElementById("p" + res[0]).innerHTML = "Zone " + res[0] + " == " + OnOff;
      }
      console.log("Topic:     " + message.destinationName);
      Log = message.destinationName;
      console.log(Log);
      if (Log == "home/irrigation/state") {
        document.getElementById("System").innerHTML = "Pump == " + mes;
      }
      if (Log == "home/irrigation/pressure") {
        document.getElementById('PumpPres').innerHTML = "Presure == " + mes;
      }
      if (Log == "home/irrigation/pump_current") {
        document.getElementById('PumpCurrent').innerHTML = "Current == " + mes;
      }
      if (Log != "home/irrigation/pump_current" && Log != "home/irrigation/pressure") {
        document.getElementById("mic").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mic").textContent + "," + mes;
        document.getElementById("mic").style.fontSize = "small";
        num = num + 1;
        Loop1();
      }
    }
    /*==========================================Functions=================================*/
    makeBigger();
    test();

    function SS_On() { //turn on the system
      var elem = document.getElementById("InputTxt") //gets the input of the textbox
      if (elem.value < 13 && elem.value >= 1) { //detects if the input is in a certan range
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(elem.value + ",On"); //wrights a message
        message.destinationName = SS_dest; //sets the destonation of the message
        client.send(message); //sends the message to the broker
      }
    }

    function SS_Off() { //turn off the system
      var elem = document.getElementById("InputTxt") //gets the input of the textbox
      if (elem.value < 13 && elem.value >= 1) { //detects if the input is in a certan range
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(elem.value + ",Off"); //wrights a message
        message.destinationName = SS_dest; //sets the destonation of the message
        client.send(message); //sends the message to the broker
      }
    }

    function makeid() { //this is made to make a randomized id
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.";

      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      return text;

    }

    function Random1() { //made for a helloworld
      var elem1 = document.getElementById("InputRandom");
      message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(elem1.value); //wrights a message
      message.destinationName = LogSS; //sets the destonation of the message
      client.send(message); //sends the message to the broker
    }

    function Loop1() { //made to reset the log
      if (num == 5) {
        document.getElementById("mic").innerHTML = mes;
        num = 0;

      }
    }

    function reset() { //ment for the reset button
      num = 0;
      document.getElementById("mic").innerHTML = " ";

    }

    function test() { //this is made to make the p1-p12 in the HTML
      for (nom = 1; nom <= 12; nom++) {
        document.getElementById("this").innerHTML = document.getElementById("this").innerHTML + "<p id=p" + nom + " class=myClass>Zone " + nom + " == Off</p>";
      }
    }

    function makeBigger() {
      var txt = document.getElementById("InputTxt");
      txt.style['width'] = '165px';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the source code?

Comment: i am new to this site to how do i do that.

Comment: Edit your question and add code as described on the help page here:  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: there you go the code is there

Comment: it works on the web page not on here though

Comment: @ben, welcome to stack overflow. Another useful page is [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These tips will help maximize your chances at getting a quality answer in return.

Comment: thank you for that i will keep those in mind for my questions in the future

Comment: What do you mean by "the text on my mobile web page increases"? Your code appends the message received to the element with id 'mic', and resets 'mic' after 5 messages are received. The HTML gets wider and wider with each message, but it wraps when it hits the window width. If that's not what you want, please describe what should happen when messages are received.

Comment: when the messages are received all the text should stay the same size and the pump should update due to the state the pump is in. Then the text at the very bottom of the page lists all of the messages that the broker is sending out.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a fixed font-size for your .myClass, hope helpful.

Comment: that still did not work. i set it to 100% and it is still doing it. If i set it to over 150% it begins to work though but i still want it to be 100% not 150%

Comment: how about font-size: 16px ?

Comment: Now it is shrinking on the mobile version on the desktop browser and increasing on the phone.